# Testing link in UIWebview before selecting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ios5, uiwebview

Right I have a UIWebview that loads a webpage once this page is loaded I then select a link using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. Is there anyway to test this link to see if it works before I select it in the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. As sometimes it hangs for about 2 minutes before actually doing anything. Like telling me theres an error.

Comment: I believe this might be able to help me. So if anyone wanted an answer look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002689/local-function-call-from-uiwebview

Comment: @Downvoter please leave reason for downvote so I can't improve question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can open the link in a hidden webview and parse the resulting html code to see whether you have a 404 error?